# Laravel 4, redirect and stop executing function

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

I have created one function for authentication and i have created another function for checking parameters. The function checkParameters accepts 2 parameters, array with input parameters that will need to be validate and the other parameter is redirectto for the route where i want to redirect. 
I call the function checkParameters inside function authenticate.
The problem is, if the validator does not run, it means that some fields are empty, i want to redirect that function. But problem occurs when the function redirects but it does not stop execution, it continues to excecute authentication function, makes api request without parameters.
How can i redirect and stop the function, to not execute the rest of the code. I want something similar like this:

```
Redirect::to($redirectto)->send();
die();
```

Answer (score 2):

to stop a function you have to use `return` operator

Answer (score 0):

a redirection in laravel is done like

```
return Redirect::to('/');
```

so this always stops execution.

(concerning your validation functions, you may want to use try catch blocks over those functions so you only have to redirect in one place - e.g. controller)

Comment: but now i have the same situation in api, i do this:

if(!$validator->passes()){
return $validator->messages()->toJson();
}
I want to return as json. And now when i call this function inside another function, it doesn't return as json, it displays blank page but at back it continues to execute the function. I neet to respond as json and to stop execution

Comment: you don't do redirection in api calls. just do `return Response::json($message)` whereas $message could be `$message = ['success' => true, 'data' => [...]]` or an error if the api call was unsuccessful.